# Byte representation of unicode string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, lua

This is python3 code:

```
>>> bytes(json.dumps({'Ä':0}), "utf-8")
b'{"\\u00c4": 0}'
```

`json.dumps()` returns unicode string and `bytes()` returns its' bytes representation - string encoded into `utf-8`.

How do I achieve the same result in Lua? I need a bytes representation of a json object which contains non-ascii chars.

Comment: You could use bitwise operators and do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it manually.

```lua
local function utf8_to_unicode(utf8str, pos)
   local code, size = utf8str:byte(pos), 1
   if code >= 0xC0 and code < 0xFE then
      local mask = 64
      code = code - 128
      repeat
         local next_byte = utf8str:byte(pos + size) or 0
         if next_byte >= 0x80 and next_byte < 0xC0 then
            code, size = (code - mask - 2) * 64 + next_byte, size + 1
         else
            code, size = utf8str:byte(pos), 1
         end
         mask = mask * 32
      until code < mask
   end
   -- returns code, number of bytes in this utf8 char
   return code, size
end

function utf8_to_python(utf8str)
   local pos = 1
   local z = ''
   while pos <= #utf8str do
      local unicode, size = utf8_to_unicode(utf8str, pos)
      pos = pos + size
      if unicode < 0x80 then
         z = z..string.char(unicode)
      elseif unicode < 0x10000 then
         z = z..string.format('\\\\u%04x', unicode)
      else
         z = z..string.format('\\\\U%08x', unicode)
      end
   end
   return z
end
```

Usage:

```lua
local json = require('json')
local x = {['Ä'] = 0}
local y = json.encode(x)
print(y)                       -->  {"Ä":0}
local z = utf8_to_python(y)
print(z)                       -->  {"\\u00c4":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version using `string.gsub`:

```
local function python_escape(str)
  return (string.gsub(
    str,
    -- leading byte followed by one or more continuation bytes;
    -- decimal version for Lua 5.1: "[\194-\244][\128-\191]+",
    "[\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]+"
    function (non_ASCII)
      local codepoint = utf8.codepoint(non_ASCII)
      if codepoint <= 0xFFFF then
        return ("\\u%04x"):format(codepoint)
      else
        return ("\\U%08x"):format(codepoint)
      end
    end))
end
```

I put parentheses around the return value `(string.gsub(--[[...]]))` to strip away the second return value of `string.gsub` (the number of replacements).